# How to create list with a string variable type and then use the list in conditionals

Tags: python

```
phrase = input["Enter a phrase: "]
vowles = ("a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U")

if (vowles) in (phrase[0:1]):
    print("an"+phrase)
else:
    print("a" + phrase)
```

Comment: You realize `input` is a function, not a `dict`, right?

Comment: Do you want to get the phrase via keyboard ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to make a little code where someone write down a sentence and if the first letter is a vowel it prints "an" and if not "a"

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong arguments and the wrong order for `in`:

```
phrase = input("Enter a phrase")
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
if phrase[0] in vowels:
    print("an {}".format(phrase))
else:
    print("a {}".format(phrase))
```

Note, however, that this is overly simplistic. It's not the *letter* a word is spelled with that determines if "a" or "an" is used, it's the *sound* a word starts with:

- a unicorn
- an hour

Comment: thanks chepner, yeh adding the sound variable would be tricky. lots of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards. The `in` operator checks if the former operand is a member of the latter operand, so you should instead do:

```
if phrase[0] in vowles:
```

Comment: appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like this

```
print ("Enter a phrase: ")
phrase = input()

vowles = ("a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U")

if (phrase[0]) in (vowles):
    print("an"+phrase)
else:
    print("a" + phrase)
```

Comment: Although `phrase[0:1]` would work in the case of strings, `phrase[0]` would be preferable. (Strings as iterables in Python are weird.)

Comment: @chepner yes. you are write. just corrected his code. thought about nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Others have shows correct version of your code, I want to note that you might done it bit different way:

```
phrase = input("Enter a phrase:")
vowels = "aeiou"
print("an" if phrase[0].lower() in vowels else "a",phrase)
```

Here I used `.lower()` method of `str`, so its enough for `vowels` to contain only lowercase vowels. This mean that you do not have to repeat yourself (c.f. DRY rule). I also used ternary conditional operator so if `phrase[0].lower() in vowels` is `true` then print is equivalent to `print("an",phrase)` and otherwsie to `print("a",phrase)`. You might think about it as more concise form of `if:`-`else:`.